# Cannot import custom rosmsg (actionlib)

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, genmsg, msg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have very strange problem related to my custom action msg. I compiled my msg, but I can't import it. When I try to run my py action server I am getting next error:

> raceback (most recent call last):
> File
> "/home/ivan/infocom_robotics_ws/src/dock_station_goal/src/turn_for_specific_angle_server.py",
> line 5, in 
> from dock_station_goal.msg import DoTurnAction, DoTurnFeedback,
> DoTurnResult ImportError: No module
> named msg

But I can at the same time I can find my msg with: rosmsg list | grep DoTurn

> ivan@ivan-desktop:~$ rosmsg list |
> grep DoTurn

> dock_station_goal/DoTurnAction
> dock_station_goal/DoTurnActionFeedback
> dock_station_goal/DoTurnActionGoal
> dock_station_goal/DoTurnActionResult
> dock_station_goal/DoTurnFeedback
> dock_station_goal/DoTurnGoal
> dock_station_goal/DoTurnResult
> ivan@ivan-desktop:~$

Another strange thing is that when I am checking: rosmsg packages, the pkgs with my custom msgs are doubled:

> ivan@ivan-desktop:~$ rosmsg packages

> actionlib actionlib_msgs
> actionlib_tutorials base_local_planner
> beginner_tutorials beginner_tutorials
> bond control_msgs costmap_2d
> diagnostic_msgs
> dock_station_goal dock_station_goal
> dynamic_reconfigure
> geometry_msgs map_msgs move_base_msgs
> nav_msgs realsense2_camera robot_drive
> roscpp
> rosgraph_msgs rospy_tutorials
> rosserial_msgs sensor_msgs shape_msgs
> smach_msgs std_msgs stereo_msgs tf
> tf2_msgs trajectory_msgs
> turtle_actionlib turtlebot3_msgs
> turtlebot_msgs turtlesim
> visualization_msgs

You can see that beginner_tutorials and dock_station_goal are doubled

I am stack and getting crazy((( Can somebody help me?

Thank you!

**EDIT**

I am using catkin_make, the output of $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH is:

/home/ivan/infocom_robotics_ws/src:/opt/ros/melodic/share

And my Cmake list is:

> cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
> project(dock_station_goal)
>
> find_package(catkin REQUIRED
> COMPONENTS   message_generation
> actionlib   actionlib_msgs
> move_base_msgs   roscpp   rospy
> std_msgs   genmsg )
>
> add_action_files(   DIRECTORY   action
> FILES   DoDocking.action
> DoTurn.action )
>
> generate_messages(   DEPENDENCIES
> std_msgs   actionlib_msgs )
>
> catkin_package(   LIBRARIES
> dock_station_goal   CATKIN_DEPENDS
> move_base_msgs roscpp rospy std_msgs
> actionlib_msgs   DEPENDS system_lib
> DEPENDS message_runtime )
>
> include_directories(
> ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
> > 
> > 
> > ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
>
> ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/340165/cannot-import-custom-rosmsg-(actionlib)/) by [Yehor](https://answers.ros.org/users/40388/yehor/) on ROS Answers with karma: 166 on 2019-12-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Yehor](https://answers.ros.org/users/40388/yehor/) on 2019-12-17**:
Another weird thing is that I can import my msg from /home/usr/my_ws by running python! But I cant import from my_pkg/src

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2019-12-17**:
Could you please **edit** your post and provide the following information:

- the `CMakeLists.txt` of your package (remove all comments, though),
- the build tool you use (`catkin_make` or  `catkin_tools / catkin build`)
- the output of `echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`
- if possible, a link to your package source code (GitHub or similar)

**Comment by [Yehor](https://answers.ros.org/users/40388/yehor/) on 2019-12-17**:
@mgruhler I edited my post

Unfortunately I don't have this project on a github

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sorry, it was my fail. I had the file with the same name as pkg in that folder and didn't notice that. Thank you for the response.

I will delete the question

---

Originally posted by [Yehor](https://answers.ros.org/users/40388/yehor/) with karma: 166 on 2019-12-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-12-17**:\

> I will delete the question

I've undeleted your question, as it is a valid question.

The fact that it has a "trivial" answer does not change this.

I've also accepted your comment as the answer.